# Check for most recent files on a shared folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using this function quite often to download new files from shared paths on the network, and to mirror certain directories on my hard drive to a shared path for others to access. It has worked quite well until I recently began working with a folder which is located across the world.

The purpose of this is to just copy any file from a folder to my computer which does not exist in a certain folder. This means that it is checking each file which is pretty expensive when dealing with a large number of files and a slow network path. I literally only need this to run daily to capture the previous dates data.

For example, filename_2016-03-12.csv is a file that I would need to download on the 13th. I do not necessarily need to check ALL files (since I did that already and ideally this should be running every day automatically). I just need the most recent files. Can I modify this to only look at the most recent files?

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
                shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Comment: Is this linux? `rsync` is purpose-built for the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
import glob
import os
most_recent_file = max(glob.glob(pathname), key=os.path.getctime)
```